# Website not scrolling fully to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a weird problem and cannot even diagnose what is causing it. I am working on my professor's website: [jurgec.net](http://jurgec.net)

The problem is only on the mobile website. If you click one of the links such as "I am an undergraduate student" then scroll down a little bit, and then press back, the website doesn't fully land at the top of the page. You can see a bit of the yellow page at the bottom.

I have a feeling its because each section's height depends on the browser's screen size. And since on mobile chrome, scrolling down causes the URL bar to disappear, it changes browser's height hence ruining the size of the website's sections.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no code controlling the back button, its just the builtin browser back button.

Comment: Just checked it out on Chrome on iOS and everything is fine.

Comment: You're right Brad, the problem cannot be recreated in iOS. Can you try Nexus 5 emulator on chrome. The problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the back button returns you to the previous "state" of the website you were at.  If you scroll down it's going to go to that part where you were when you made the Click.

Does $(document).ready() functions fire after a back button press??  If they do (not sure at the moment) you could do something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  scroll(0,0) 
});
```

Which if that works shouldn't really affect you because on initial page load you are already at (0,0) so you wouldn't notice any jumping.  Not sure if this would work for you, but good luck!

Comment: Shouldn't it automatically scroll to the top? I don't want to force it. (I am not scrolling away from the top initially, so I expect to return back to the top).

Comment: Didn't you say that you were scrolling down a little bit before clicking the link?

Comment: Not exactly, this is how I recreate the issue: load the website, click one of the buttons (takes you to a section lower down in the page), scroll, click back. Now I don't load at the top of page, even though that's where I started.

Comment: I can not reproduce that issue.  I tried it on my phone, as well as all the emulators within chrome.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. I can consistently reproduce the bug.  Steps: open new chrome window, load jurgec.net, click third button, scroll approximately half section height down, press back. Now you won't land fully at top of page. If it doesn't work, try scrolling a bit more before hitting back or with button 2.

Comment: I did exactly that.  I am sorry but I can not reproduce.